# Is it possible to list all actions of a macro using VBA in a MS Access database?

Tags: vba, ms-access

In MS Access, using VBA, I need to **list all actions in a macro**, so that I can see what dependencies that macro has: what queries or additional macros it launches.
With the following query I can retrieve a list of all the macros in a database:

```
SELECT Name, Type, DateCreate, DateUpdate FROM MsysObjects 
WHERE (Name Not Like '~*') And (Name Not Like 'MSys*') 
And Type=-32766     
ORDER BY Name;
```

Is there anything like a 'MacroDef' object, similar to TableDef or QueryDef, that could provide further details of a macro?
Might there be any profane hidden system table which stored the list of actions in a macro?

Thanks a lot for any tip or guidance to move forward on this.

Comment: If there is, it's probably a deep hidden table. Review http://www.mendipdatasystems.co.uk/purpose-of-system-tables/4594446646. Lists one called MSysMacros.

Comment: Excellent resource, thank you!! A pity thay in my Ms Access version, the MSysMacros is not available (version: Office 365 ProPlus).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have some luck using the undocumented `.SaveAsText` method to output the information to a text file, and then read these text files back in using VBA. Try something like:

```
Sub sExportObjects()
    On Error GoTo E_Handle
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim cnt As Container
    Dim doc As Document
    Dim strFolder As String
    strFolder = "J:\downloads\test\"
    Set db = DBEngine(0)(0)
    Set cnt = db.Containers("Scripts")
    For Each doc In cnt.Documents
        Application.SaveAsText acMacro, doc.name, strFolder & "macro_" & doc.name & ".txt"
    Next doc
sExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    Set cnt = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    Exit Sub
E_Handle:
    MsgBox Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "sExportObjects", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number
    Resume sExit
End Sub
```

Regards,

Comment: Get 'Type Mismatch' error on `For Each doc In cnt.Documents`. Why the item named "Scripts"?

Comment: Okay, I get the name "Scripts", still get Type Mismatch.

Comment: This works https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1175611

Comment: My version works OK for me. The one that you have linked to is pretty much the same. The only thing that I can think of is that you may need to declare `As DAO.Container` and `As DAO.Document` if you have other libraries referenced that contain Container and Document objects.